# Why Mockito's mock returns 0 when it should return null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

When there's some object with a boxed type property, the getter of the property returns `0`. But this should return `null`, because the default value of the boxed type property is `null`. What is the problem here?

```
class Person {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
...

@Mock Person person;

...
person.getId(); // 0 instead of null
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile: The return type of the getId() method is missing. And it's rather important, because if it's Long, then the default value (for uninitialized objects) is null. If it's long, then the value for uninitialized longs (primitives) is 0, although in this case I would expect a NullPointerException when trying to unbox the null Double. But please correc the code?

Answer (score 14):

That's simply the chosen default value for primitive and wrapper types in the default Mockito answer.

This `0` default has been chosen when `null` was used and too many users experienced NPEs due to unboxin, hard to diagnose for novices in particular, when `null` was used.
While this might be surprising for people used to reference and un/boxing, this trade-off was worth it in usability.

One day maybe this could be revisited when/if Java gets a nullability notation reachable via reflection.

And regardless mockito allows you to change the default answers if it doesn't suit the project/team.

Comment: Was it not possible to diversify the return values?

Comment: You can customize default values when stubbing of course. But I assume you meant change the default value of the default answer, in this case no it's not currently implemented, however it is possible to change the default answer of a mock.

Comment: i would expect a `null` for a `Long` and a `0` for a `long`

Comment: @aliopi That opinion has been discussed a while ago, primitive wrappers, are for primitive and shouldn't be returned as null. That may feel opinianated, but we strongly support good programming practice and as such we avoid to return null where possible.

Comment: Yes, in your sandbox/context yes. But here at work, returning `0` instead of `null` for a `countX`-method leads me to believe the service found `0 ` objects, when in fact it was the mock being opinionated.

Comment: @aliopi This is documented. This defaut has worked for almost everyone in years. If you would like to raise the subject on github please do so, this way this point can be seen by other commiters and contributors ; however I don't think this will ever be changed.

Comment: I like Mockito a lot, don't get me wrong. I can live with this. Just saying there are different perceptions.

Comment: @aliopi Fair enough ;)

Comment: Mockito seems overly opinionated on this. The default should match the value for uninitialized class variables of the same type, 0 for int/short/long, null for Integer/Short/Long.

Comment: @XXLuigiMario It's easy to say _overly opiniated_ while you didn't had to handle the maintainance and support the library and the consequences of the alternatives. This default has been chosen because too many users experienced NPEs hard to diagnose issues due to unboxing for novices in particular when `null` was used. This trade-off was worth it in usability. Maybe this could be revisited when/if Java gets a nullability notation reachable via reflection.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and my solution was to change the default answer of the mock to `null`:

```
Person person;

...
person = mock(Person.class, new Answer<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    return null;
  }
});
person.getId(); // null!
```

(Not sure if the default answer can be set if you want to use the `@Mock` annotation)

If for some reason you would only like to set the default for `Long` (and not for example `Integer`) this should do the trick inside the `answer` method:

```
if(invocation.getMethod().getReturnType().equals(Long.class)){
  return null;
}else{
  return Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can just create a `Person` mock as you normally would (e.g. `mock(Person.class)`) and stub its `getId()` method to return `null` as follows: `when(person.getId()).thenReturn(null)`.

Answer (score -1):

That is the correct value that is getting returned for the getter method.

When you Mock a class in Mokito all the methods in the class also get mocked. so inherintely this does not matter with the boxed type property being set to Null. As you see its LONG value that you have as a instance variable whose default value is 0L.

So person.getId() will always return 0 and not NULL.

Comment: Can you explain in detail